# Modify Maven dependency download process

Tags: maven

I have written a small server that allows downloading a diff between two versions of a Maven dependency and thus download fraction of the size and still have the whole file at the end.

Currently, I use an external code to first download the dependencies and put them in the `.m2` download cache.

My question is if there is a way to hook into the download process of Maven to handle the download of dependencies myself?

Comment: Maybe you could write a Maven extension (not a plugin) that gets in between the download process ... it will probably not be easy. I would be genuinely interested in the use case: Do you have very large and constantly changing dependencies?

Comment: We are using maven to manage external installers required by our app and they change pretty frequently. Some installer are 100MB with bsdiff of only 15MB so it is huge win

Answer (score 0):

The short answer I've found is `Wagon`, that is an interface you can implement as part of Maven Extension to add new repositories types.

I've found an implementation of such an extension, called [CloudStorageMaven](https://github.com/gkatzioura/CloudStorageMaven) that I'm trying to use to build my own implementation.